# How can I extract known number of digits from string with unknown length?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a couple of strings that look like:

```
data_20220110_073030.gz
ndsfhsfihso_20100330-100210.gz
l0dnd74n-19981001.180800.gz
```

I only want to extract information above that has 8 or 6 digits and are all numerical values from 0-9. Ideally, it would be output to a single array / list such as:

```
[20220110,073030]
[20100330,100210]
[19981001,180800]
```

I know one can use regex, but I can't seem to get it into an array.

Comment: `re.findall()` returns a list of all the matches. What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
(?<!\d)\d{6}(?:\d\d)?(?!\d)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qGMdnl/1)**.

**Details:**

- `(?<!\d)` - Not immediately preceded by a digit.
- `\d{6}` - Match exactly 6 digits.
- `(?:\d\d)?` - And (optionally) two more digits.
- `(?!\d)` - Not immediately followed by a digit.

**Python example:**

```
import re

regex = r"(?<!\d)\d{6}(?:\d\d)?(?!\d)"
test_str = """data_20220110_073030.gz
ndsfhsfihso_20100330-100210.gz
l0dnd74n-19981001.180800.gz"""

arr = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(arr)
```

**Output:**

```
['20220110', '073030', '20100330', '100210', '19981001', '180800']
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/JJIY5712)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python Regular Expression library to find the sequence of characters that forms the search pattern you are looking fro

Example

```
import re

text = 'data_20220110_073030.gz ndsfhsfihso_20100330-100210.gz l0dnd74n 19981001.180800.gz'

x = re.findall('\d\d\d\d\d\d', text) #for 6 digits sequence
y = re.findall('\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d', text) #for 8 digits sequence

print(y)
print(x)
```

you can impove on  that by having a function create the pattern base on the length of digits you want

```
import re

def digitSequence(length: int, text: str):
    pattern = ''
    for i in range(length):
        pattern += '\d'
    
    return re.findall(pattern, text) # returns a list of match's found

print(digitSequence(8, text))
print(digitSequence(6, text))
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. The first `findall` will match substrings that are part of a 7+ digit numbers and the second one will match substrings that are part of 9+ digit numbers. So, if you have an 8-digit number, you end up matching it twice (when it should only be one match). Same goes for a 9-digit number (except that it should return 0 matches).

Comment: ```import re

def digitSequence(length: int, text: str):
    pattern = ''
    for i in range(1, length):
        pattern += '\d'
    
    return re.findall(pattern, text) # returns a list of match's found

print(digitSequence(8, text))
print(digitSequence(6, text))```